# Grouping like records

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

We have a set of data where there are 2 records for each `CODE`.  An example of the data is this:

```
TICKER    CODE    SCORE    PRICE    PCF
---------------------------------------
ABC        23       A       100      20
DEF        23       B       200      30
XXX        52       C       300      40
YYY        52       D       400      50
GHI        86       E       500      60
JKL        86       F       600      70
MNO        27       G       700      80
PQR        27       H       800      90
```

So, what we need to do is create a query which will return the columns of the like records by CODE into 1 record like this:

```
CODE,TICKER_1,SCORE_1,PRICE_1,PCF_1,TICKER_2,SCORE_2,PRICE_2,PCF_2
23,ABC,A,100,20,DEF,B,200,30
52,XXX,C,300,40,YYY,D,400,40
86,GHI,E,500,60,JKL,F,600,70
27,MNO,G,700,80,PQR,H,800,90
```

So, that they are combined by like `CODE` values.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following which assigns  uses `ROW_NUMBER` to assign a row number for each code entry before using `MAX` with a  case expression to filter for each entry.

Eg.

```sql
SELECT
    CODE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN TICKER END) AS TICKER_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN SCORE END) AS SCORE_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN PRICE END) AS PRICE_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN PCF END) AS PCF_1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN TICKER END) AS TICKER_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN SCORE END) AS SCORE_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN PRICE END) AS PRICE_2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn=2 THEN PCF END) AS PCF_2
FROM (
    SELECT 
        m.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY TICKER) as rn 
    FROM mytable m
) m1
GROUP BY
    CODE
```

Outputs:

| CODE | TICKER_1 | SCORE_1 | PRICE_1 | PCF_1 | TICKER_2 | SCORE_2 | PRICE_2 | PCF_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | ABC | A | 100 | 20 | DEF | B | 200 | 30 |
| 27 | MNO | G | 700 | 80 | PQR | H | 800 | 90 |
| 52 | XXX | C | 300 | 40 | YYY | D | 400 | 50 |
| 86 | GHI | E | 500 | 60 | JKL | F | 600 | 70 |

For debugging purposes, the output of the subquery

```sql
    SELECT 
        m.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY TICKER) as rn 
    FROM mytable m
```

looks like this:

| TICKER | CODE | SCORE | PRICE | PCF | RN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 23 | A | 100 | 20 | 1 |
| DEF | 23 | B | 200 | 30 | 2 |
| MNO | 27 | G | 700 | 80 | 1 |
| PQR | 27 | H | 800 | 90 | 2 |
| XXX | 52 | C | 300 | 40 | 1 |
| YYY | 52 | D | 400 | 50 | 2 |
| GHI | 86 | E | 500 | 60 | 1 |
| JKL | 86 | F | 600 | 70 | 2 |

[View working demo on db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=01066d774a065446dc60dc925d0328c6)

**Notable alternatives**

- Instead of `CASE WHEN rn=1 THEN TICKER END` you could also use the `DECODE` function available in oracle as `DECODE(rn,1,TICKER)`
- You may also use a pivot as shown below (*NB. Column names are not as in the expected result*)

```sql
WITH cte as (
    SELECT 
        m.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CODE ORDER BY TICKER) as rn 
    FROM mytable m
)
SELECT * FROM cte 
PIVOT (
    MAX(TICKER) as "TICKER",
    MAX(SCORE) as "SCORE",
    MAX(PRICE) as "PRICE",
    MAX(PCF) as "PCF"
    FOR rn IN (1,2)
)
```

Outputs:

| CODE | 1_TICKER | 1_SCORE | 1_PRICE | 1_PCF | 2_TICKER | 2_SCORE | 2_PRICE | 2_PCF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | ABC | A | 100 | 20 | DEF | B | 200 | 30 |
| 27 | MNO | G | 700 | 80 | PQR | H | 800 | 90 |
| 52 | XXX | C | 300 | 40 | YYY | D | 400 | 50 |
| 86 | GHI | E | 500 | 60 | JKL | F | 600 | 70 |

[View working demo on db fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=23853d647cdf7ae9e1cab94e98d685d8)

Comment: I think this will work.    The query is a bit larger, but with what I've tested with thus far, it appears to give the proper data.    Much appreciated!

Comment: I do like the smaller query, but any way to get the 1_ or 2_ to the other side?  _1 / _2 ?

Comment: @LandonStatis Change from `SELECT *` to use named columns with aliases. `SELECT "1_TICKER" as ticker1,` etc.

Comment: @LandonStatis MT0 is right. see example in [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6ee644999169f08678f224247c0c5a35) or you may attempt to rename it in your sql client/application.

Comment: Just want to say thanks to you all.   This has helped out a lot!

Comment: Oracle is better than MS Sql server for pivoting allowing multiple aggregations and aliasing. TSql only allowed SELECT * FROM cte 
PIVOT (
    MAX(TICKER)
    FOR RowId IN ([1],[2])) as pvt